# Signing arbitrary data with x509 in Java

Tags: java, cryptography, x509

I have an API which which provides authentication via a signed response to a random chalange.  Server sends a random string to the client, the client signs this data using a previously established key pair and then sends this data back to the server.  I need the format of the signature to be something roughly equivalent to the PGP clear sign or detached signature format.  Is this possible to do using only the official Java APIs e.g. no bouncy castle?

Comment: What is wrong with java.security.Signature?

Comment: it doesn't encapsulate the signature in an standardized exportable format which is sharable across application and language barriers.  That is what PKCS7 was designed for.

Comment: I think your comment would have been valuable information in your question. And your answer breaks the rules given in the last sentence of your question.

Comment: 'roughly equivalent to the PGP clear sign or detached signature format'

Answer (score -2, accepted):

oracle.security.crypto.cert.PKCS7